# Updating CLOB XML through updatexml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, updatexml

I have one tag in my table having clobe xml data like as below:

I need to update this value to 400. I am doing it as below. But its not updating. Please help.

UPDATE XYZ
SET request_xml = UPDATEXML(xmltype(request_xml),
   'Parameters/Parameter[@Name="ABC"]/@Value', 400,'xmlns:n0="http://www.iQWE.com/LKJ"').getClobVal()
where transaction_id = '2017051907471800000000187725';

Comment: <n0:MaxLatenessAllowed Value="0.0"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath doesn't make much sense. You are looking for a node called `Parameter` with an attribute called `Name`, where that attribute value is `'MaxLatenessAllowed'`. There is nothing like that in your XMl document.

You can supply the full path to the node you want to change, including namespace info:

```
UPDATE dfxha_catchup_queue
SET request_xml = UPDATEXML(xmltype(request_xml),
   '/n0:CreateOrder/n0:SalesOrders/n0:SalesOrder/n0:SalesOrderLines/n0:SalesOrderLine/n0:MaxLatenessAllowed/@Value',
    400,
    'xmlns:n0="http://www.i2.com/DFX"').getClobVal()
where transaction_id = '2017051907471800000000187725';
```

Or to shorten that you can look for that node name anywhere, if that's safe in your schema:

```
UPDATE dfxha_catchup_queue
SET request_xml = UPDATEXML(xmltype(request_xml),
    '//n0:MaxLatenessAllowed/@Value',
    400,
    'xmlns:n0="http://www.i2.com/DFX"').getClobVal()
where transaction_id = '2017051907471800000000187725';
```

The `updateXML()` function [is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/UPDATEXML.html), so you might want to investigate other ways of achieving this.